# AWS Attach dynamic policy to identityId of a logged in user in post-authentication trigger lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

The story so far:
We want to generate IOT policies on-demand when a user logs in based on a specific set of rules.
We want to then attach those policies to the identityId of the user that has just logged in using a mobile application (cognito user).

We managed to do this by calling another lambda, to be more precise, we have a lambda that is called using a POST request, and inside that POST request, the mobile app sends the `identityId` of the logged in user, so problem solved.

We were wondering (and trying) if there is an option to do this operation in one of the post-authentication triggers that cognito supports. So far, I haven't managed to do that.

From what I have already read from the documentation I know so far that:

1. I can't get the token in the post-authentication lambda trigger, so I can't use cognito-idp to get the id of the logged in user within that lambda.
2. I cannot get the identity id from the event/context of the lambda either, so that does not help.

Is there a way to attach a policy to a user that has just logged in, but inside the post-authentication lambda triggers?

Answer (score 0):

I would say as follows :

Enable the "Invoke a Lambda function" option in the post-authentication trigger of your Cognito user pool. This will cause Cognito to invoke your Lambda function after a user logs in.

In your Lambda function, you can use the AWS SDK to create an IAM policy and attach it to the user's identity ID. Here's an example code snippet:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const identityId = event.request.userAttributes.sub;
  const policyDocument = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      }
    ]
  };
  
  const policyParams = {
    IdentityId: identityId,
    PolicyName: "my-policy",
    PolicyDocument: JSON.stringify(policyDocument)
  };
  
  await cognitoidentity.setIdentityPoolRoles(policyParams).promise();
  
  return event;
};
```

This code creates a new IAM policy with the required permissions and attaches it to the user's identity ID using the setIdentityPoolRoles method of the CognitoIdentity SDK.

Note that you'll need to have appropriate IAM permissions to create and attach policies in your Lambda function. You may also need to adjust the policy document and resource ARNs to match your specific use case.

Comment: Hi & thanks for the answer! 
Unfortunately, this line is not entirely correct `const identityId = event.request.userAttributes.sub;`, as `sub` is not the same with `identityId`. Maybe it works with IAM policies, but it does not work with IOT Policies.